# DevExpress WinForms TileView Format Rule

Tags: devexpress

I converted my gridview to tile view and I added some format rules. When I run my project, format rules doesn't work.I'm sure my rule is correct. What should I do ?

Comment: You need to post some more information for someone to be able to help you. Do you get any errors? How does your format rule look?

Comment: I don't get errors. Just happen nothing. My rule is a simple rule. If STATUS column text equals a string, my tile's background color will change. But it's not work.

Comment: you should provide some code to understand the scenario.. and one more thing tile view use skin to draw the background color. if you want to customize the tile conditionally then you should handle [TileView.ItemCustomize Event](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsTileTileView_ItemCustomizetopic)

Comment: Thank you. I fixed my problem using TileView.ItemCustomize event.

My Code:

private void tileView1_ItemCustomize(object sender, TileViewItemCustomizeEventArgs e)
        {
            string adres;
            TileView view = sender as TileView;
            
            if (!view.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "adres").Equals(DBNull.Value))
            {
               adres = (string)view.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "adres");
            } 
            if (adres == "")
            {
                    e.Item.AppearanceItem.Normal.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I discovered till now, **To customize the tile conditionally then you should handle [TileView.ItemCustomize Event](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsTileTileView_ItemCustomizetopic).**

Refer this: [Tile View](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument17629)

> The TileView.ItemCustomize event fires for each tile before this tile
>   is displayed. When handling this event, you can read its e.Item
>   parameter to access the completely generated, ready to be displayed
>   tile item. Afterwards, you can apply required changes. For instance,
>   apply a different background color or access the TileItem.Elements
>   collection to modify specific elements.

All TileViewItemElements within the view can be customized by accessing appearance settings available through the [TileView.AppearanceItem](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsTileTileView_AppearanceItemtopic.aspx) property. At the same time, each individual element has its own appearance settings that override this global appearance. To access these appearances, use the [TileItemElement.Appearance](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsTileItemElement_Appearancetopic.aspx) property.

example:

```
private void tileView1_ItemCustomize(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Tile.TileViewItemCustomizeEventArgs e) {
    e.Item.Elements[6].Text = String.Format("${0}M", ((Decimal)(Int32)tileView1.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, colPrice) / 1000000).ToString("0.0"));
    if ((bool)tileView1.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, colSold) == true) {
        e.Item.Elements[1].Image = global::TileViewHomes.Properties.Resources.gray_element;
        e.Item.Elements[6].Text = "SOLD";
        //Changes background colour of non selected tileitem
        e.Item.AppearanceItem.Normal.BackColor = Color.Red; 
    }
}
```

References:
[tileView_ItemCustomize is not updating until resize](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T194906)

Comment: Thanks.I used tihs event and its worked but I used this way in another project when I run my project an error occurs. "object reference not set to an instance of an object" 

When I look e.Item argument I noticed e.Item argument is null. I have no idea why its null. My other project works fine but this isn't work.

Comment: it is hard to say anything about your another project scenario of usage. it will be impossible to guess without any information.  create another SO thread with some information and error code  where you are having problem.